# Using Sed to search and replace JSON using regex from stdin

Tags: regex, sed

How would I use sed to search for the regex `"pk": [0-9]+` in stdin and replace it with `"pk": null`?

e.g. convert `"pk": 123` to `"pk": null`

I've tried something like:

```
cat mydata.json | sed -e s/\"pk\"\:\s[0-9]+/\"pk\"\:\snull/g
```

but this has no effect. Cutting the regex back, it seems to break at `[0-9]+` but I'm not sure why as this is both a simple and valid regular expression. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the cat is not necessary.

```
sed 's/\(.*:\s*\)[0-9]\+/\1null/' file
```

if you need exactly `pk`:

```
sed 's/\("pk":\s*\)[0-9]\+/\1null/' file
```

e.g.

```
kent$  echo '"pk": 123'|sed 's/\(.*:\s*\)[0-9]\+/\1null/'
"pk": null
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
sed -e 's/"pk": [0-9]\+/"pk": null/g' mydata.json
```

Comment: as I knwe, Jaypal won't use `cat` in that way.

Comment: @Kent Sorry, I just copied OP's attempt at `sed` command and modified it. :(

Comment: It has to use piped stdin. I use mydata.json only as an example. I don't actually have a literal file.

Comment: @Jaypal exactly what I thought. :D

Comment: Piping should work as well: `cat mydata.json | sed 's/"pk": [0-9]\+/"pk": null/g'`